# Sys.WebForms.Res is undefined

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms

- .NET 4.51 Webforms
- VS2013 Update 1

I started with a brand new Web project selecting both WebForms and MVC support. Been working on it for a couple of days locally with no problem. However now that I web deploy it I am getting the error:

TypeError: Sys.WebForms.Res is undefined

Having read other posts it appears this has something to do with ScriptManager etc. So below is my master page script manager block:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
        <%--Framework Scripts--%>

        <%--<asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />--%>   
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />      
        <%--Site Scripts--%>
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>

<div class="container body-content">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphMainWithoutUpdatePanel" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updMain" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphMain" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

I have jQuery declared in the head as:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The only reference to AJAX in the web.config:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
     <system.web>
        <authentication mode="None" />
        <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        <pages>
          <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
            <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" />
          </namespaces>
        </pages>
```

Aside from the update panel I am not using anything MS AJAX AFAIK. So no AjaxControlToolkit. I have no custom JS calls in the page.

So as this all works locally it leads me to believe that something is different on the remote server. However for the life of me I cannot work it out. Has anyone got any suggestions?

Really need to get this live so any help or suggestion no matter how far fetched happily received.

Comment: Do you get any other errors in the console of the browser's debugger? This error is probably coming from MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js (I think). If you're not using any Ajax stuff, have you tried removing the MsAjaxBundle bundle?

Comment: In which browser you are getting this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up solving this. In my case this issue arose because there was some other low level exception within code/controls that were found within an update panel.

Once the above error was corrected everything worked the Res error went away. Now if I have a low level error such as EF problem or similair the error comes back. Annoying but at least I know what it is and how to deal with it.

Comment: Hi, I have exact similar issue like yours. I have similar application structure and .net 4.5 too. The application works fine within Visual Studio 2013 but once I deployed it - in my case it is Azure, this error appears. How did you find out about the other low level errors you were getting?

Comment: I added a global exception handler and logged anything through there. I also logged as the application started up so I could isolate how far the application was getting before it blew up. Then I knew where to focus my efforts.

Answer (score 2):

```
<add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

Check if the web.config has the above code block.

Source: [Resolving the "Sys is undefined" error in ASP.NET AJAX RTM under IIS 7](http://geekswithblogs.net/lorint/archive/2007/03/28/110161.aspx)

It looks like the problem is related to the browser not downloading the compressed script, the other possible causes are discussed in [demystifying-sys-is-undefined](http://weblogs.asp.net/chrisri/archive/2007/02/02/demystifying-sys-is-undefined.aspx) blog entry. A commenter in this page has provided an approach to deal with this Sys, although it looks like a hack. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bootstrap and you are using a modal. I found two causes:-

1. If you have Response.Write anywhere in the code. Removing it fixes the issue.
2. ANY error in your code. Best to first run the code in a separate web page, this will give a more descriptive error detail. Then after fixing the error, you can us the modal

Comment: Response.Write was the cause of mine, I'd put it in there to debug something else

Answer (score 1):

Use the settings below in your web.config file.

```
<system.web>
<xhtmlConformance mode="Transitional"/>
</system.web>
```